# Rearrange an array according to key

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, associative-array

I dont know what to ask so i straight away went to show an example. Hope it helps though!
Say i have an array

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => int 1
      1 => int 2
      2 => int 3
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => int 2
      1 => int 3
      2 => int 4
  5 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => int 5
      1 => int 6
      2 => int 7
```

Now i want to arrange it according to **KEY** so that it looks like

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => int 1
      1 => int 2
      2 => int 3
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => int 2
      1 => int 3
      2 => int 4
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => int 5
      1 => int 6
      2 => int 7
```

Does anyone has a solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible approach:

```
$new_arr = array_values($old_arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `foreach` and assign the values to new `array`

```
$newArr = array();
foreach($array as $k=>$v){
    $newArr[] = $v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most direct way to achieve that is probably to run `array_values` on your array :

```
$array = array_values($array);
```

It will basically reset the keys